# How to combine multiple result sets into one table with While loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that gets the correct data, but it doesn't output it the way I would like.

The query is as follows:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<review><score>98</score><gameid>99</gameid><reviewdate>11/11/11</reviewdate><reviewtitle>Skyrim : A Real Masterpiece </reviewtitle><reviewdescription>Skyrim is the best open world-game ever made.</reviewdescription></review>';
DECLARE @dataCount int, @currentNodeIndex int;
DECLARE @outputTable TABLE (Rating nvarchar(max), GameId nvarchar(max), DateReviewed nvarchar(max), Title nvarchar(max), Description nvarchar(max));

SET @dataCount = @xml.query('count(/review/*)').value('.', 'int');
SET @currentNodeIndex = 1;

WHILE @currentNodeIndex <= @dataCount
BEGIN
  SELECT @xml.query('/node()[1]/node()[sql:variable("@currentNodeIndex")]/node()[1]').value('.', varchar(max)') as Temp
  FROM GameData;
  SET @currentNodeIndex = @currentNodeIndex + 1;
END
```

This generates the correct data, but like this:

```
Temp
 98

Temp
 99

Temp
11/11/11

Temp
Skyrim : A Real Masterpiece

Temp
Skyrim is the best open world-game ever made
```

I would like for this to display in one table, in one horizontal line, using the Alias created from the @outputTable

So like

```
Rating GameId DateReviewed Title Description
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should just do an Insert into your temp table with a select from your XML.

Comment: But I am only fielding one record with the loop for each iteration.

Comment: You don't need a loop. With the Insert with Select you can insert all rows with all column values in one shot, please see answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<review><score>98</score><gameid>99</gameid><reviewdate>11/11/11</reviewdate><reviewtitle>Skyrim : A Real Masterpiece </reviewtitle><reviewdescription>Skyrim is the best open world-game ever made.</reviewdescription></review>';

DECLARE @outputTable TABLE (Rating nvarchar(max), GameId nvarchar(max), DateReviewed nvarchar(max), Title nvarchar(max), Description nvarchar(max));

--Do your insert into the temp table with select from xml
INSERT INTO @outputTable
SELECT a.value('score[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [Rating], a.value('gameid[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [GameId], a.value('reviewdate[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [DateReviewed], a.value('reviewtitle[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [Title], a.value('reviewdescription[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [Description]
FROM @xml.nodes('/review') AS x(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a logical answer but is there a way to do this with a loop? It sounds bizarre but I want to try this first.

Answer (score 0):

To parse rows of xml and output into a query then I would go about it a bit differently.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Data XML)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('<review><score>98</score><gameid>99</gameid><reviewdate>11/11/11</reviewdate><reviewtitle>Skyrim : A Real Masterpiece </reviewtitle><reviewdescription>Skyrim is the best open world-game ever made.</reviewdescription></review>'),
('<review><score>100</score><gameid>1002</gameid><reviewdate>11/11/12</reviewdate><reviewtitle>Skyrim : A Real Masterpiece </reviewtitle><reviewdescription>Skyrim is 222the best open world-game ever made.</reviewdescription></review>')


SELECT
    Score = Data.value('(/review/score/.)[1]', 'INT'),
    GameID = Data.value('(/review/gameid/.)[1]', 'INT'),
    ReviewDate = Data.value('(/review/reviewdate/.)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(10)'),
    ReviewTitle = Data.value('(/review/reviewtitle/.)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(300)'),
    ReviewDescription = Data.value('(/review/reviewdescription/.)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM  
     @T
```

Comment: Your approach is technically superior but I was wondering if I can utilize the while loop.

Comment: Or is this not feasible?

Comment: If you need to loop then you either have to know the structure up front of you will have to unpivot a node-name / node-value temp table.